# Clicking a "add comment" button

Tags: record, selenium-ide, playback

When I am recording my script my scrpit is failing when it is coming to the part of clicking the "add comment" icon. The error I am getting is that the element is not found. The html script is :

a id="cmt_place" class="btn add_comment" onclick="javascript:SNI.Community.Toolbox.TopNavCheckandShow()">

So I am confused which command I should use and what the target and value should be so that when the test runs it should be able to automatically click the add comment icon.

New        Test Case

```
open    /registration/login.esi     
type    id=up-ur-email             
type    id=up-ur-password       

click   css=#up-ur-widget-login > #up-ur-widget-nav-item-off > a > em   
open    /home/home.esi  
click   link=TEST_upload    
click   id=Add Comment  
click   id=commenttext  
type    id=commenttext                test123
click   css=#post-comment-omnt > em     
clickAndWait    link=Log Out
```

Answer (score 0):

```
open    /registration/login.esi     
type    id=up-ur-email             
type    id=up-ur-password       

click   css=#up-ur-widget-login > #up-ur-widget-nav-item-off > a > em   
open    /home/home.esi  
click   link=TEST_upload 
Pause   30000
click   id=Add Comment  
click   id=commenttext  
type    id=commenttext                test123
click   css=#post-comment-omnt > em     
clickAndWait    link=Log Out    


pause command will pause 3 second before click the  Add comment button. 

Try this.

Thank you.
```

Answer (score 0):

use Xpath of comment box in target field and  use pause & setCursorPosition command
pause to wait for some time and setCursorPosition command to point comment box

```
open    /registration/login.esi     
type    id=up-ur-email             
type    id=up-ur-password       
click   css=#up-ur-widget-login > #up-ur-widget-nav-item-off > a > em   
open    /home/home.esi  
click   link=TEST_upload   
click   id=Add Comment(use Xpath of comment box instead of this)
pause   2000
setCursorPosition   id=commenttext
click   id=commenttext  
type    id=commenttext                test123
click   css=#post-comment-omnt > em     
clickAndWait    link=Log Out
```